# chrome declarativeNetRequest append matched url not working

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I'm trying to append the matched domain from a declarativeNetRequest rule to the redirect extension page, but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. The redirect is working to my extension page but the matched URL isn't appended.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  const page = chrome.runtime.getURL('/MyPage.html');
  const RULES = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'priority': 2,
    action: {type: 'redirect', redirect: {regexSubstitution: page + '#\\0', extensionPath: '/MyPage.html'}},
    'condition': {
      regexFilter: "\w*",
      requestDomains: ["amazon.com"]
    }
  }]

  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: RULES.map(r => r.id),
    addRules: RULES,
  });
```

Updated code snippet:

```
    const page = chrome.runtime.getURL('/MyPage.html');
    const RULES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      priority: 2,
      action: {type: 'redirect', redirect: {regexSubstitution: page + '#\\1' }},
      condition: {
        regexFilter: "https://([^/]+)",
        requestDomains: ["amazon.com"]
      }
    },
    ];
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
      removeRuleIds: RULES.map(r => r.id),
      addRules: RULES,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `, extensionPath: '/MyPage.html'` as you already have a substitution
2. Replace `\w*` with `://([^/]+)` to capture dots and dashes in the domain name, also note that inside regexp *strings* you need to use an escaped backslash `\\` not `\`  while there's no need to escape the forward slash `/`.
3. replace `#\\0` with `#\\1` to get the parenthesized group of the above regexp.

Comment: I've updated my code to use what you suggested and it's now showing "Open xdg-open?" dialog when a rule is matched (I'm on Ubuntu) not sure what is happening.. it's not opening the extension html page anymore either

Comment: Did you list MyPage in web_accessible_resources? Also see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73392754).

Comment: I do: "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": ["MyPage.html"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }]

Comment: If my linked example doesn't work for you either it may be a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll raise a bug in chrome for this.